# lambda using tuple via reflection

Tags: c#, linq, reflection, lambda, entity-framework-6

I have some code to sync Entity Framework POCOs between different database servers (source server is SQL Server, destination is MySQL). It is written to work generically using the `[Key]` attribute and the fact that the POCOs representing the data being synced know how to compare themselves.

The code is currently as follows:

```
var srcdbset = setprop.GetValue(src, null); var dstdbset = setprop.GetValue(dst, null);
var tabletype = srcdbset.GetType().GetGenericArguments().First();
var keys = tabletype.GetProperties().Where(p => p.GetCustomAttributesData().FirstOrDefault(a => a.AttributeType.Name == "KeyAttribute") != null).ToList();

var param = Expression.Parameter(tabletype);  // TODO - support compound keys
var dt = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(tabletype, keys[0].PropertyType);
var df = Expression.Lambda(dt, Expression.Property(param, keys[0].Name), param).Compile();
var qtodict = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods().Where(m => m.Name == "ToDictionary").First();
var gtodict = qtodict.MakeGenericMethod(new[] { tabletype, keys[0].PropertyType });
var srcdict = ((IDictionary)gtodict.Invoke(null, new object[] { srcdbset, df }));
var dstdict = ((IDictionary)gtodict.Invoke(null, new object[] { dstdbset, df }));
var qexcept = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods().Where(m => m.Name == "Except").First();
var gexcept = qexcept.MakeGenericMethod(new[] { keys[0].PropertyType });
dynamic snotd = gexcept.Invoke(null, new object[] { srcdict.Keys, dstdict.Keys });
dynamic dnots = gexcept.Invoke(null, new object[] { dstdict.Keys, srcdict.Keys });
```

A little help - `src` is the source `DbContext` and `dst` is the destination `DbContext` and `setprop` is the `PropertyInfo` object of the `DbSet` being synced.

This question really isn't so much about Entity Framework, but linq and reflection. As you can see the TODO comment says - "support compound keys" - the code above works fine for POCOs with just one key, but to support composite keys, the lambda expression needs to change from something like:

```
dbcontext.Accounts.ToDictionary(a => a.AccountID);
```

to something like:

```
dbcontext.OntLocations.ToDictionary(l => Tuple.Create(l.OntID, l.LocationID, l.Index);
```

The two linq expressions immediately above are obviously written in a non generic way to make things simpler to explain - my question is - how do I write a generic lambda that does the tuple create? If anyone could point me in the right direction on that, I think the rest of the code would work as is.

Also, you are probably thinking - why aren't they using transactional replication - long story short - unable to find a product that works reliably - if anyone knows of one that works well from SQL Server to MySQL and doesn't require much/any downtime to the SQL Server to install I'm all ears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer by [@Dave M](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46106120/lambda-using-tuple-via-reflection/46107242#46107242) is fine, but the whole thing can be greatly simplified by emitting a call to one of the [`Tuple.Create`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.create(v=vs.110).aspx) method overloads using the following handy [`Expression.Call`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351107(v=vs.110).aspx) method overload

```
public static MethodCallExpression Call(
    Type type,
    string methodName,
    Type[] typeArguments,
    params Expression[] arguments
)
```

which will do the most of the work for you:

```
var source = Expression.Parameter(tabletype, "e");
var key = Expression.Call(typeof(Tuple), "Create", 
    keys.Select(pi => pi.PropertyType).ToArray(), // generic type arguments
    keys.Select(pi => Expression.MakeMemberAccess(source, pi)).ToArray() // arguments
);
var keySelector = Expression.Lambda(key, source).Compile();
```

Later on, `key.Type` property can be used to get the tuple type.

Comment: Many thanks to you both - with insight from both answers I was able to add in support for composite keys with an extra 5 lines of code!

Answer (score 2):

First you will need to get the type of tuple you need to create, this has to be hard-coded per number of keys since the Tuple class is actually a different class depending on the number of items:

```
Type tupleType = null;
if(keys.Count == 1) tupleType = typeof(Tuple<>);
else if(keys.Count == 2) tupleType = typeof(Tuple<,>);
else if(keys.Count == 3) tupleType = typeof(Tuple<,,>);
else if(keys.Count == 4) tupleType = typeof(Tuple<,,,>);
//and so on

tupleType = tupleType.MakeGenericType(keys.Select(t=>t.PropertyType).ToArray());
```

Now you can make the Func as you had it above:

```
var lambdaFuncType = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(tabletype, tupleType);
```

Now build the expression to create the tuple. We'll need the tuple constructor and a property accessor expression for each key.

```
var parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(tabletype);
var constructorExpression = Expression.New(tupleType.GetConstructors()[0], 
    keys.Select(t=>Expression.Property(parameterExpression, t.Name)).ToArray());
```

Now make the full lambda and compile it:

```
var compiledExpression = Expression.Lambda(lambdaFuncType, constructorExpression, parameterExpression).Compile();
```